Anime movie: woman dies, wakes up as a cat girl
It's like an old anime movie and I watched it on YouTube about 5 years ago. I'm not sure what year it was made, but I'm pretty sure it was lost at some point because the description mentioned it as lost media.
The movie begins with one girl who's talking to a guy and then she gets killed because someone shoots her or pushes her off a building. Then she wakes up as a cat girl.
She meets up with some friends that she had (I think, but I'm not sure) and one of them is a guy who takes care of her while the other is a woman who gets jealous.
In one scene (the only scene that's like this, the rest is wholesome and honestly really great but I wanna watch it again) she imagines them having sex, which was weird and unnecessary but nonetheless I think the movie was great and I'd like to know the name of it.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

i watched it on youtube and it was about 5 years ago
